# Assigning an array to a single key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to assign an array to a single key.

I'm trying to assign an array of values to a single key as follows:

$entity_items_array[$entity_restrict] = $entity_items;

The key, $entity_restrict, looks like this:

```
'User'
```

The array, $entity_items looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 [14] => 14 [15] => 15 [16] => 16 [17] => 17 [18] => 18 [19] => 19 [20] => 20 [21] => 21)
```

And I'm trying to assign the key as follows:

But for some reason, when I look at $entity_items_array, the value I get is:

```
Array ( [0] => user )
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I not assigning data to the array correctly?

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're using? The problem will likely present itself then.

Comment: Assignment is correct the values must be wrong. Try to reproduce this result in example code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$entity_items_array = array();
$entity_restrict = 'User';
$entity_items = array(0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3); 

print_r(array_fill_keys(array($entity_restrict), $entity_items));
```

Just another method.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted seems to work.  I took it and reproduced it and got this:

```
$entity_items_array = array();
$entity_restrict = 'User';
$entity_items = array(0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3); 

$entity_items_array[$entity_restrict] = $entity_items;

print_r($entity_items_array);
```

That output this:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
    )
)
```